# display number of users per month in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, bar-chart

I want to create a bar chart that display the bar + number of qty of total users visited the site in google analytics so that I can export it as pdf. As it is now it only display line charts which only display the total number for each month when hovering over the chart values in the the browser. If I export it to pdf it does not show me the qty of users in the line chart. I would like to display it like in this image..

[image]

Can this be done in google analytics?

Answer (score 2):

You can get it done by using [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on). You'll need to use the Add-on to pull the data from Google Analytics, to your Google Sheet in order to generate your chart.

**Creating the report**

1. Install the Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on by following the steps defined [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on#installing-the-add-on).
2. Once installed, create a new spreadsheet on Google Sheets.
3. Select "Add-ons" > "Google Analytics" > "Create new report".
4. On the "Create a new report" sidebar, name your report as "Monthly Users Report" and select the view where the data will be pulled.
5. Under Dimensions, select "Month of the year".
6. Under Metrics, select "Users".
7. Click Create Report to create the report.
8. You should now see a Report Configuration Sheet being created.

**Configuring the report**

9. Now you'll need to enter the date range for your data. For example purposes, lets put 2018-01-01 as the start date, and 2018-12-31 as the end date.
10. Now run the report to fetch the data. To do this, select "Add-ons" > "Google Analytics" > "Run reports".
11. Once successfully run, you should see a new Sheet being created with the name "Monthly Users Report.

**Generating the chart**

12. Create a new sheet.
13. Select "Insert" > "Chart". You should see the Chart editor.
14. Under the Data tab, enter 'Monthly Users Report'!A15:B27 as the Data range.
15. Under the Customize tab, select "Series" and make sure Data labels is checked.
16. All done! Feel free to customize the chart accordingly.

Hope that helps!